# Property [id] does not exist in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Why i am keep getting this error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

My method:

```
public function modes()
{
    $modes = Genre::limit($this->limit)->get();


    return new GenresResource($modes);
}
```

My Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name
    ];
}
```

M Model

```
class Genre extends Model {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'genres';

protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to change your controller method to indicate that it's receiving a collection, not a single model.

```
$modes = Genre::limit($this->limit)->get();

return GenresResource::collect($modes);
```

Generally you'll want to give your resource a singular name so you may want to consider calling it `GenreResource` too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand - your `$this` is a `Collection`, not `Model`. Obviously the collection does not have properties `id` and `name`.

Comment: Okay, I want make json transformer,  how can i do that? i added my model